# Login Page for Asp.Net Web Application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I have web application using master pages. I want the login page to be the first page to display when a user navigates to this site. The login page is a content page. When I use the Asp.Net demos and the configuration web site the provide for setting security, my application doesn't render any of the styles. Is there a better tutorial to lock down an entire web application and how to use security?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allow anonymous access to your resources (CSS, JavaScript etc.) in your web.config file. If you don't, then they'll not be served until you log in.

Have a read of [Setting authorization rules for a particular page or folder in web.config](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx)

Example:

```
<configuration>
    <location path="mystyles.css">
       <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/> 
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Here is another helpful link [Login Master Pages](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/904091-unable-get-login-page-using-master-page-display-styles-forms-authenticatio)

Answer (score 0):

If you have used form authentication then just add following section in your web.config

```
 <location path="App_Themes"> (location of your style resource)
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

so style would have anonymous access. for automatically redirect anonymous user  to login page
you have to add login url as per below

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="30"></forms>
</authentication>
```